# Empty page after webpack production build IIS

Tags: node.js, iis, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a VUE 2 application which I want to deploy on an IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2.

node version: 6.9.5
npm version: 4.3.0

My problem is, when I call the site (index.html and static folder with js and css generated by webpack) the site remains blank. All js and css files are loaded correctly, but the site doesn't show anything.

Here are my config files for webpack:

bundle.js:

```
require('./check-versions')()

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'

var ora = require('ora')
var rm = require('rimraf')
var path = require('path')
var chalk = require('chalk')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.prod.conf')

var spinner = ora('building for production...')
spinner.start()

rm(path.join(config.build.assetsRoot, config.build.assetsSubDirectory), err => {
  if (err) throw err
  webpack(webpackConfig, function (err, stats) {
    spinner.stop()
    if (err) throw err
    process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
      colors: true,
      modules: false,
      children: false,
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false
    }) + '\n\n')

    console.log(chalk.cyan('  Build complete.\n'))
    console.log(chalk.yellow(
      '  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.\n' +
      '  Opening index.html over file:// won\'t work.\n'
    ))
  })
})
```

webpack.base.conf.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  externals: {
    'jquery': 'jQuery'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    modules: [
      resolve('src'),
      resolve('node_modules')
    ],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      'src': resolve('src'),
      'assets': resolve('src/assets'),
      'components': resolve('src/components')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: "pre",
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
        options: {
          formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

webpack.prod.conf.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
  ? require('../config/test.env')
  : config.build.env

var webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? '#source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      sourceMap: true
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css')
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin(),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
        ? 'index.html'
        : config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: false,
        removeAttributeQuotes: false
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: function (module, count) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      chunks: ['vendor']
    }),
    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  var CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

config.js:

```
// see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack for documentation.
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  build: {
    env: require('./prod.env'),
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../wwwroot/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../wwwroot/'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '',
    productionSourceMap: true,
    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
    // Run the build command with an extra argument to
    // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
    // `npm run build --report`
    // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  },
  dev: {
    env: require('./dev.env'),
    port: 80,
    autoOpenBrowser: true,
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '',
    proxyTable: {},
    // CSS Sourcemaps off by default because relative paths are "buggy"
    // with this option, according to the CSS-Loader README
    // (https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#sourcemaps)
    // In our experience, they generally work as expected,
    // just be aware of this issue when enabling this option.
    cssSourceMap: false
  }
}
```

.bablerc:

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "stage-0" ],
  "plugins": [ "transform-runtime" ],
  "comments": false,
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [ "istanbul" ]
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "coreui-vue",
  "version": "1.0.0-alpha.4",
  "description": "Open Source Admin Template",
  "author": "Łukasz Holeczek <lukasz@holeczek.pl>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs test/e2e/specs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "auth0-js": "^8.8.0",
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "mini-toastr": "^0.6.5",
    "strip-ansi": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "vue": "2.2.4",
    "vue-chartjs": "2.5.4",
    "vue-notifications": "^0.8.0",
    "vue-router": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-strap": "github:wffranco/vue-strap",
    "vue-video-player": "^3.0.8",
    "vuex": "^2.3.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "6.7.7",
    "babel-core": "6.24.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "3.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "6.24.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "chromedriver": "2.28.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "3.2.4",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "0.26.4",
    "eslint": "3.18.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "6.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^2.0.7",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "3.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "2.1.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "4.15.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "1.6.1",
    "function-bind": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.4",
    "inject-loader": "2.0.1",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.2.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.26",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "lolex": "^1.5.2",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "nightwatch": "0.9.13",
    "opn": "^4.0.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "ora": "^1.1.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "4.1.1",
    "selenium-server": "3.3.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "sinon": "1.17.7",
    "sinon-chai": "2.9.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.4",
    "vue-style-loader": "2.0.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.2.4",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.8.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {

  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  }
}
```

I moved the devDependencies also to the dependencies to be sure, that's not the problem.

My generated index.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8><title>CoreUI - Open Source Bootstrap Admin Template</title><link href=static/css/font-awesome.min.css rel=stylesheet><link href=static/css/simple-line-icons.css rel=stylesheet><link href=static/css/style.css rel=stylesheet><link href=static/css/app.06e44e579e587787413ab48c2c604c4d.css rel=stylesheet></head><body class="app header-fixed sidebar-fixed aside-menu-fixed aside-menu-hidden"><div id=app></div><script type=text/javascript src=static/js/vendor.2cb2e5935748c34893e8.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=static/js/app.9dc82c9f50710d9ababd.js></script></body></html>
```

With the webpack dev server it work's. And also on my local machine with express. 
I don't understand what's happening...

After the webpack build I can add this to the iis as normal website, correct? There is no need for iisnode.

Thank you!

Dominik

EDIT:

Image of dev tool:

[image: Dev Tool]

[image: Browser]

[image: Console]

Comment: Have you looked in your devtools? Is your bundle.js loading, and is it called? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: See my edit and the added pictures. I don't see anything suspicious.

Answer (score -1):

I had been running into this issue as well. I'm running Vue.js 2.0 App under .NET Core using IIS. The build was displaying as a blank page under Chrome, with no error messages even tho all assets were being downloaded correctly.

Turns out I had to enable the use of **eval** + **inline scripts** in `web.config` file, under the 'Content-Security-Policy' custom header:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
 <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Hope this helps out!